# Getting XKB remaped arrow keys (ISO_Level3_Shift + HJKL) to work properly with the WIN key under X11

Tags: keyboard, xorg, keyboard-layout, xkb

I've seen some posts on how to remap arrow keys under X11 with XKB, but although they work mostly fine, no method so far (except using different groups, which become an hassle to manage with Gnome keyboard-setup) seems to work together with the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key.

I'm trying to remap my keyboard so that HJKL keys allow me to have navigation with a `ISO_Level3 modifier`.

I tried both assigning the arrow keys directly in ISO_Level3 and by **redirecting** the key (I give both examples in the code below).

They work alone fine (i.e. I can use the arrow keys by themselves) and they also work with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd> (i.e. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>LVL3</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> = <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>LEFT</kbd>) but they **don't work together with the WIN key**.

My symbol file is:

```
default partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "basic" {
      name[Group1] = "Satan";
      include "us"

      // middle row
      key <AC06> {
        symbols =   [ h, H, Left ],
        actions =   [ NoAction(), NoAction(), Redirect(key=<LEFT>) ] };
      key <AC07> {      [ j, J, Down ] };
      key <AC08> {      [ k, K, Up ] };
      key <AC09> {      [ l, L, Right ] };

      key <AC10> {      [ ISO_Level3_Shift, colon, semicolon, colon ]};
      modifier_map Mod5 { ISO_Level3_Shift };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

## description

I've found a solution that works well for me in most cases, but not all applications seems to interpret xkb input directly. It was a little more complex than using the level 3 modifier, though. In my case, I mapped `CAPSLOCK`to set a control layer called `Overlay1`.

I don't really understand the inner workings of xkb, but it seems that this layer is not affected by other modifiers. With that, `win`+`CAPS`+`{h,j,k.l}` moves windows around (in my setup)

following is the relevant section of [my xkb file](https://github.com/avila/dotfiles/blob/master/keyboard/xy):

```
partial modifier_keys xkb_symbols "xy_caps_overlay" {

    replace key <CAPS> {
        type[Group1] = "TWO_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1] = [ Overlay1_Enable, Overlay1_Enable ],
        actions[Group1] = [ SetControls(controls=Overlay1), LockControls(controls=Overlay1) ]
    };
    // Movement Section
    key <LatH> { Overlay1 = <LEFT> };
    key <LatJ> { Overlay1 = <DOWN> };
    key <LatK> { Overlay1 = <UP>   };
    key <LatL> { Overlay1 = <RGHT> };

    key <TAB>  { Overlay1 = <TAB>  };

    // Editing Section
    key <LatQ> { Overlay1= <Esc>    };

    key <LatZ> { Overlay1 = <UNDO> };
        key <UNDO> { [ VoidSymbol ],
            actions[Group1]=[ RedirectKey(key=<LatY>,modifiers=Control)] 
        };
    key <LatY> { Overlay1 = <REDO> };
        key <REDO> { [ VoidSymbol ],
            actions[Group1]=[ RedirectKey(key=<LatZ>,modifiers=Control)] 
        };
    key <LatX> { Overlay1 = <CUT>  };
    key <LatC> { Overlay1 = <COPY> };
    key <LatV> { Overlay1 = <PAST> };

    key <LatQ> { Overlay1 = <ESC>  };
    key <LatU> { Overlay1 = <HOME> }; 
    key <LatI> { Overlay1 = <END>  }; 

    key <LatP> { Overlay1 = <PGUP> }; 
    key <AC10> { Overlay1 = <PGDN> };

    key <LatD> { Overlay1 = <DELE> };
    key <LatB> { Overlay1 = <BKSP> };

    key <SPCE>  { Overlay1 = <RTRN>  };

};
```

make sure to include this `partial` in your layout, such as

```
        include "xy(xy_caps_overlay)"
```

where xy is the name of the file this partial settings are written, and xy_caps_overlay is the actualy name of the partial section.

## note

Maybe my file is rather confusing. But note that I ALSO use the third level modifier (AltGr, or Right Alt) for, sometimes, overlapping purposes, so I can also navigate around with only my right hand, but the using `AltGr` + `Win` + `{h j k l}` does not work as intended.

## bonus

(further down in my files are some other interesting stuff I am experimenting with, but is not directly related to your question, but you might be interested on. See `xy_greek_lvl2` section for how I use `AltGr`+`,` or `.` to latch or shift the keyboard for maths (greek) characters.) (its a working in progress though a bit messy)

Excerpt here (in case I move the files around)

```
    key <RTSH> { // Use right shift (with shift) while pressed 
            symbols[Group1] = [ NoSymbol, NoSymbol ], 
            actions[Group1] = [ SetMods(modifiers=Shift,clearLocks), LatchGroup(group=2) ]
    };
    key <AB08> { // use "," for 2nd group (with AltGr) while pressed
            symbols[Group1] = [ NoSymbol, NoSymbol, VoidSymbol, VoidSymbol ], 
            actions[Group1] = [ NoAction(), NoAction(), LatchGroup(group=2) ]
```